# Determining bluetooth version and specs

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have a built-in Bluetooth device, and I'm trying to setup [BlueSoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/).  It asks for information like baud rate, flow control, stop bits... Where can I find this information?

Is there a [CPU-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) type of program for Bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I'll address the second part of the question, since I don't actually know a nice program which will give you information you need about the bluetooth radio itself. I usually had to rely on finding the information on the chip itself using hardware ids provided by Windows.

The baud rate, flow control, stop bits and so on are setting for serial port running over the bluetooth. All recent USB based bluetooth adapters should be able to run with any of the settings, so what you need isn't a function of the adapter. It's a function of the target device to which you're trying to establish serial connection. To get the information from the remote device, you should read its manual. It will mention required settings. If it doesn't say anything, you can try some common settings.

Some of the common settings are 9600 b/s, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no flow control, no parity bits. This is used by all kinds of laboratory equipment, serial terminals and various hobby bluetooth modules.

A more recent setting is 115200 b/s, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no flow control, no parity bits. It will allow faster communication.

Some GPS receivers use 4800 b/s, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no flow control, no parity bits.

Do note that there should be no way to actually damage the remote device using incorrect settings, You may receive gibberish over terminal when you try to send commands, but there should be no hard that a reset won' fix.

If you aren't actually trying to connect something using serial over bluetooth, just set the port to 9600 b/s, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no flow control, no parity bits. That's more or less the default setting for serial ports. If you actually have to change it, you'll know that.

Do note that many many devices which use bluetooth, like mice, headsets, mobile phones and so on do not actually require you to set up the serial port by hand and may not even use the functionality of the serial port over bluetooth.

Comment: Let me go a step back.  How do I know what kind of bluetooth I'm using? UART, PCMCIA, BCSP

Comment: @wizlog It could be any of them, but since you're using BlueSoleil with it, I'd bet it's USB bluetooth adapter. Did it show up in hardware devices in control panel? The best way to find out what kind of device it is is to find it in control panel->system->device maanger. It should be listed under bluetooth radios.